# Actualizar información de una columna a otra en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT NUM_EMP_SEP, 
       NUM_EMP_OCT 
FROM CONTADOR 
WHERE NUM_EMP_OCT IS NOT NULL
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que la misma información que se encuentra en la columna `NUM_EMP_OCT` se copie a la columna `NUM_EMP_SEP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con una sentencia de actualización:

```
UPDATE CONTADOR 
       SET NUM_EMP_SEP = NUM_EMP_OCT
       WHERE NUM_EMP_OCT IS NOT NULL
```